# 404 Error jsf application

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am new to JSF, and I am making a simple jsf application.  I am getting a 404 Error when I try to run the application on using Tomcat, and I'm not sure why.  I tried running the application from eclipse and not from eclipse and neither works.  I've tried multiple different urls (all case sensitive), including localhost:8080/testing/faces/index.jsp, localhost:8080/testing/index.jsp, and localhost:8080/testing/, and none of them work.  As far as I can tell, my files are all in the correct place (my jsp files are under WebContent, my web.xml and my faces-config are in WEB-INF).  Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my code?  I have pasted my web.xml and my faces-config below.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>testing</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF
                 Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
the rendered HTML output.
If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
that submits the corresponding form.
If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
will be added as url parameters.
Default is 'true'</description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
        i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
        influence the HTML code.
        Default is 'true'
  </description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <description>
If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
Default is 'false'

  </description>
  <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>faces/index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
     <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>results</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>testing.model.Results</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>tuple</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>testing.model.Tuple</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>WEB-INF/index</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>true</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/WEB-INF/newValsIndex.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<navigation-rule>
    <display-name>WEB-INF/index</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/WEB-INF/index.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>false</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/WEB-INF/failedLogin.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Which book/tutorial/resource was you using while learning JSF? It look like that you mixed JSF 1.x and 2.x resources. This is a no-no. In JSF 2.x a lot of things are done differently, among others, JSP is been deprecated and succeeded by Facelets (XHTML). I recommend to just throw away everything and restart with a sane JSF 2.x resource. You can find some links in [our JSF wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). Also, I wonder which tutorial exactly it was as putting apparent public resources in `/WEB-INF` just doesn't work at all (this part is in turn not related to JSF at all).

Comment: I looked at tutorials on a variety of different sites (most notably http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaServerFaces/article.html), and I used the template there to try to make my own jsf application.  Most of the code above was generated by eclipse.  What parts of my code is jsf 2.x and what is jsf 1.x?  Thanks!

Comment: That tutorial is JSF 1.x targeted. Anything from before December 2009 is guaranteed JSF 1.x. Please throw away everything and head to JSF 2.x resources. There's so many wrong in the code created/generated so far that I don't know where to start answering/fixing (and thus your question is basically unanswerable). Follow the link given in my previous comment to get started the right way.

Comment: Okay, I'm looking through the link now. Thanks for the help!